# FBSDKLoginBehavior.Web opening modal web view as well as opening browser

Tags: ios, facebook, uiwebview

I am trying to implement Facebook sdk, everything working good,

```
    var fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.Web
    fbLoginManager .logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            var fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result

        }
```

I am using the above code to login with Facebook, however I saw a modal UIWebview opening however the browser also opening which should not because I am not using:

```
fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.Browser
```

Comment: Yes, If I will not set any behaviour, then it will open up on browser however I am setting the behaviour to web which should open up UIWebview modal

Comment: Brother..it also opens up browser as well means it opens both. why That is my question

Comment: Because of issues introduced by the update to ios 9 I would go ahead and not indicate a login behavior, so FB determines the best experience for the user based on his iOS version and presence of the native FB App.